# change play/stop button angularjs

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a basic play-stop control

When I click on the play button, I want it to change to a stop button. and viceversa. this code is working but it made a ugly refresh. the stop button shows before the play button hide. and viceversa. any idea?

in html

```
<div style="margin-top: 1%;margin-left: 10%">

<button class="media-object button-icon ion-ios-play botonesPlayStop" ng-show="playVisible"
ng-click="btnReproducirAudio()"></button>

<button class="media-object button-icon ion-stop botonesPlayStop" ng-hide="playVisible"
ng-click="detenerAudio()"></button>
```

in js

```
var ruta= "/android_asset/www/sounds/beep.amr";
$scope.audiofile = new Media(ruta);

$scope.detenerAudio = function () {
        $scope.audiofile.stop();
        $scope.playVisible=true;

};

$scope.btnReproducirAudio() {
        $scope.audiofile.play();
        $scope.playVisible=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` there is a little delay for updating the view. It's always better using `ng-if` (also for the DOM).

Another, maybe better but not to much, way:

HTML:

```
<button class="media-object button-icon botonesPlayStop" ng-class"{'ion-ios-play': playVisible, 'ion-stop': !playVisible}" ng-click="playOrStop()"></button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.playOrStop = function () {
    if($scope.playVisible){
       $scope.audiofile.play();
    }else{
       $scope.audiofile.stop();
    }

    $scope.playVisible = !$scope.playVisible;
};
```